# Checking for a button click

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery

I want to redirect the page to a different location according to the button clicked, i want something similar to this:

```
if(document.getElementById('button').onclick == true)
{ 
  //redirect page
}
```

However this code is not working for me:

```
document.getElementById('button').onclick = function() {
  //redirect page
}​;​
```

Comment: 1) which language is the 1st ("…similar to this") codeblock in?
2) the javascript code in the second block works for me, see this codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eNaNKm

Comment: have you tried `document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', function() { alert('hellooo!'); });`

Comment: I have edited my question, i hope that helps. The second code block is not working seamlessly for me.

Comment: Are you using `asp:button` or `html's button` ?

Comment: cshtml5, im coding in mvc 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be easily acheived also with javascript:

```
<button id="btn" onclick="redirect()">redirect</button>
<script>
    function redirect()
    {
        window.location = "http://www.google.com/";
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

the simplest way to do is add onclick() event in button tag.

```
<button id='button' onclick='redirectThePage();' >Click Me</button>
```

and in javascript

```
function redirectThePage(){
//redirect page
}
```

another way to do is

```
<button id='button'>Click me</button>
```

and in javascript

```
var button = document.getElementById('button');
button.onclick = function() { // redirect the page };
```

Comment: Can't this be achieved without jQuery? Can you help by explaining what is wrong in the code given in the OP?

Comment: yes we can do with javascript also edited the answer, check now

Answer (score 3):

There are different ways to do the same thing.

### 1. `addEventListener()`

```
document.getElementById('button').addEventListener("click", function() {
    redirect();
}​);​

function redirect(){
    //redirect page
}
```

**Pro**

- No nesting javascript and HTML

**Contra**

- More code
- Can't see in HTML code whats happens by click

### 2. `onclick` (answered by [slashy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32034437/checking-for-a-button-click/32034558#32034558))

**Note:** If you find this better, all owner goes him/her.

```
<button id="btn" onclick="redirect()">redirect</button>
<script>
    function redirect() {
        //redirect page
    }
</script>
```

**Pro**

- Less code
- You can see in HTML code what there happens by a click event

**Contra**

- Nesting HTML and Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery:

```
$('#button').click(function(){
    window.location.href = "index.php";
});
```

HTML:

```
<button id="button">Click next</button>
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding _how_ and/or _why_ it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.